# How to solve offline range-mex query with updates?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

**ATTENTION!** I have read all same questions on stack and some other sites.
All of them are wrong or working more than TL.

Now about the task:

Size of input array: `N <= 5*10^5 and 0 <= array[i] <= N`

(The size of the array is less or equal to 5*10^5, each element is less or equal to the array size)

Queries: `Q <= 2,5*10^5`

We must answer the query(`l r`) as [MEX-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)) on range `[l, r]` of input array or proceed query(`p x`) as `array[p] = x`

Hope, u can help me with some ideas)

Comment: The accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633225/please-tell-me-the-efficient-algorithm-of-range-mex-query looks to me like a good solution. Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: And if you're doing it offline, you should be able to simplify things by sorting the queries by start index. You could build a state machine and answer all the queries in a single sequential pass of the input array. Not sure on complexity of building the state machine, though.

Comment: @JimMischel It is not clear what we store in the node of the segment tree. Is this a RMinQ + array of last positions?

Comment: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/57934

Comment: @juvian How can 'simple segment tree with sum on a range' can help with calculating mex?

Comment: @user10101134 no idea, the simplest solution is from misof only using sets

Comment: @juvian Yep, this is cool solution, but i have an array, not a set. May be u can help me, how to project that solution to my question?

Comment: my bad didn´t notice you had queries on range. Then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139325/mex-queries-with-updates

Comment: @juvian This is wrong solution.

Comment: How is it wrong?

Comment: @juvian If the same numbers are missing in the ranges, but missing_value of these ranges are different, then there will be an incorrect answer. Something in this spirit

Comment: @juvian Oh, if u check comments under that solution, u will find the example of wrong case

Comment: @user10101134 how many elements can the array have?

Comment: @juvian N(you can see above)

Comment: Thought N was the highest number each element could have

Comment: @juvian The size of the array is less or equal to 5*10^5, each element is less or equal to the array size

Comment: can only think of O(n^(5/3) * log n) solution in both time and space :\

Comment: @user10101134 what is the time limit? Have problem link?

Comment: @juvian Hmm, this is strange, because it does not depend on Q

Comment: was just considering Q < N

Comment: @juvian Unfortunately not, ma friend told me the task. The TL is 5s

Comment: @juvian This looks like some sqrt-decomposition, am i right?

Comment: @user10101134 yes, not sure if my solution would run in 5s

Comment: @juvian I would be glad if you share your ideas with me. Perhaps it will push me to a new idea.

Answer (score 0):

- Separate the array into blocks of size n<sup>2/3</sup>. This will leave us with n<sup>1/3</sup> blocks.
- For each pair x y of blocks, x < y, keep a count of each number that appears in the range arr[x * n<sup>2/3</sup>...y * n<sup>2/3</sup>] and then make a set with the missing numbers. There are n<sup>2/3</sup> such pairs, counting is O(n), making the set is O(n log n) => O(n<sup>5/3</sup> * log n)
- For an update, we will update all pairs of blocks where the position is in range. An update consists of decreasing 1 from count of current value, if count gets to 0 add the value to the set and then add 1 to the count of new value and remove that value from the set. This is O(log n) for each pair of blocks, which gives us  O(n<sup>2/3</sup> * log n) cost for each update.
- For a query, find the biggest block pair that is fully enclosed within query bounds. Then look at array values missing from those bounds both to the right and to the left and sort them. With this + the missing values set we can calculate the mex for the range. Note that we must check to the left and to the right at most 2n<sup>2/3</sup> values, so sorting will cost O(2n<sup>2/3</sup> * log 2n<sup>2/3</sup>). This is the cost for each query.

All in all, complexity is  O(n<sup>5/3</sup> * log n + u * n<sup>2/3</sup> * log n + q * 2n<sup>2/3</sup> * log 2n<sup>2/3</sup>) with q being the amount of range queries and u the amount of updates.

A bit of optimizations:

- For an update, you can use lazy update and just let the ranges know that we need to make that update, but only do an update on a pair of blocks when it is required by a query.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is over the TL(

Comment: @user10101134 is the preprocessing all pairs before queries giving TL or after?

Comment: just because O(N^(5/3)logN)